# Get Auto-Layout to work with Notification Center width for Today Extension in iOS 8

Tags: ipad, widget, ios8, autolayout

For an iOS 8 Today Extension I am trying to position multiple square views in a way that they use the total width of the Notification Center.

Using Auto-Layout I got it to work as expected on the iPhone 5S and below. Everything works fine on these 4-inch and below devices because the Notification Center uses the whole screen width in both portrait and landscape mode.

However, the new iPhone 6(+) and all iPads do not use their whole screen width do display the Notification Center. This is what messes up my views. They still fill up the whole width of the NC, but they are not squares anymore but stretched vertically. I guess that Auto-Layout is being presented with a width of the whole screen width and does its calculations. In a second step however the NC then shrinks the views horizontally in order to fit them in the NC. This results in rectangles rather than squares.

How can I avoid this behavior? Seems to be a bug to me but any idea of a workaround?